# Is MS Exchange overkill for simple email to .NET functionality (like newsgroup email posting functionality)?

Tags: .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have a Bizspark enrollment for my startup. I need functionality where user's can send email to `theirusername@mystartuptld.com` and it will parse it out and add it to their work queue (like basecamp does).

I'm considering using MS Exchange for this for a number of reasons:

1. It's free with my bizspark.
2. It's MS and with EWS it seems like it would play nice with my .net application
3. It would make it easy to also host my email up there etc.

Is this overkill? Should I look at a more simple solution? Or are there other reasons Exchange would be a bad choice for this?

FYI, I am NOT an Exchange admin nor do I know anything about it so this will be all new to me.

Comment: Will that Bizspark Exchange license ever expire?

Comment: Not that I know of. Once you have the software, it's yours.